# copy sorted file contents in remote hosts using Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I would copy the `sort content` of the `/tmp/test` file into the `/tmp/test_sort` and i would get the same output format file which will be created using the `lookup` plugin lookup and i am using this playbook:

```
              - hosts: all
                gather_facts: yes
                become: true
                vars:
                  file_contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/test')|sort}}"


                tasks:
                  - name: copy
                    copy:
                      content: '"{{file_contents}}"'
                      dest: /tmp/test_sort
                      remote_src: yes
```

the `/tmp/test` files contains this content:

```
banana
apple
car
juice
ananas
@chicken
```

after excuting the playbook i get this in the `/tmp/test_sort` file:

```
"['\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '@', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'p', 'p', 'r', 's', 'u']"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are sorting letters. Sort lines.

```
"{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/test').splitlines() | sort}}"
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply after adding the `.splitlines()` i got this:
`"['@chicken', 'ananas', 'apple', 'banana', 'car', 'juice']"`. This is the order that i am looking for but i would get the same output as the '/tmp/test' file i mean a list

Comment: join array with newlines `| join('\n')`

Comment: thank you so much exactly `| join('\n')` did the job